# jQuery Ajax, MVC and the Querystring

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following ajax function on my view in a ASP.NET MVC3 website. This function is called from a list in the top of the page, and it works great. But I need another value from the querystring, that needs to be passed to the controller function. How Do i achieve this ?

jQuery function

```
   function ShowDeals(itemNo) {
    //get the vendor



    var dialogDIV = $('<div></div>');
    $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/Deal/Index',
            type: "POST",
            data: ({ toets: itemNo }),
            dataType:'html',
            success: function (result) {
                $(dialogDIV).html(result);
                $(dialogDIV).dialog({
                    position : [,100],
                    error: function (req, status, error) {
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
            },
            error: function (req, status, error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        })
        return false;
    }
```

Controller Action

```
public ActionResult Index(int toets,string vendorNo)
    {
        string temp = toets.ToString();
        string tempdd = Request.QueryString["vendorNo"];
        //return Content("1212121212");
        return PartialView();
    }
```

The toets parameter is passed from the ajax function, but I now need the vendorNo that is in the Querystring.

Thanks

EDIT : I know I can add a javascript function to get the value from the querystring, but is that the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass that in the same way you pass in your `toets` param:

```
var vendor = $("#TheElementThatHoldsYourVendor").text();
$.ajax(
{
    url: '/Deal/Index',
    type: "POST",
    data: ({ toets: itemNo, vendorNo: vendor }),
    ....
});
```

And then you'd have it as the second parameter, you don't have to access the `QueryString` to fetch it.

**EDIT**
To fetch a url parameter using javascript, you could use this method ([from here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/09/get-url-parameters-values-with-jquery.html))

```
function getUrlVars()
{
    var vars = [], hash;
    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        vars.push(hash[0]);
        vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }
    return vars;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: { toets: itemNo, vendorNo: getUrlVars()['vendorNo'] }
    ...
});
```

Comment: The vendor is not displayed on the page. What happen is the user log into the system, a list of vendors is displayed, using an Actionlink the user is then redirected to the Items page, and the Ajax method is called from one of these items. So the $("#TheElementThatHoldsYourVendor") is the querystring.

Comment: Oh, I see. But that won't be in the querystring of your AJAX, so you need to pass that in manually with js.

Comment: @CaptainOrgange: Made an edit to show how to fetch url params with javascript

Answer (score -1):

```
function ShowDeals(itemNo) {
    //get the vendor

    var venderNo = $("#TheElementThatHoldsYourVendor").text();

    var dialogDIV = $('<div></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Deal/Index?vendorNo=' + venderNo,
        type: "POST",
        data: ({ toets: itemNo }),
        ...
}
```

If the controller action is looking for a query string, you need to add the query string to the url.